# Required Field Validator for Dropdown not working

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

Any reason why the required field avlidator for this dropdown wouldn't work? I am binding items from database.

This is the cascaded dropdown by the way.[Here's the image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPyAS.png)

Comment: What you mean by not working? explain more. as it stands, your question should be closed as unclear.

Comment: If I click on submit button without selecting any dropdown option, the required field validator is not getting fired.

Comment: What you have currently should work fine. You need to post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequiredFieldValidator` control only works if the selected value (ListItem) from the DropDownList is blank.

For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select from the list...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Alpha</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Bravo</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Charlie</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_List" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="ddlList" ErrorMessage="Select from the list." />
```

You can also use HTML5's required attribute instead of using a validator control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server" required>
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select from the list...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Alpha</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Bravo</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Charlie</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: this isn't true as I've been able to make use of `RequiredFieldValidators` and setting the selected value to "-1"

Comment: @terbubbs Point taken. But I intentionally did not include the InitialValue property so the default value must be blank.

Comment: If you do want to have an `InitialValue` try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165174/requiredfieldvalidator-not-working-for-dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Enabled="false"` from the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Comment: Is the `ValidationGroup` set on your submit button?

Comment: Lana, that doesn't matter actually

Comment: Since it's set on the `RequiredFieldValidator`, I believe it needs to also be set on the controls to validate, as well as the button that's causing validation to occur. As it stands, it's only set on the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Comment: I did solve the problem eventually from codebehind but I still wonder why it's not working from aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because your default list item value is -1, try to use

```
<asp:ListItem value="">...</asp:ListItem>
```

or RangeValidator